# How is it possible to store the beta when doing regressions?

Tags: r

I have a dataset df with the following structure (data for illustration):

| Date | Stock | Return | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.20 | A | 4.4 | 3.3 | 3.0 | 6.3 |
| 01.01.20 | AAPL | 5.5 | 4.3 | 3.1 | 7.1 |
| 02.01.20 | A | 2.34 | 3.2 | 3.3 | 1.9 |
| 02.01.20 | AAPL | 1.11 | 9.5 | 4.5 | 3.3 |

I am running a regression on stock returns of 390 different stocks, each at 4870 different days.

For a stock, I am running the following line:
`lm(Return ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = subset(df, Stock = "A"))`

This gives the three betas for the specific stock (in this example "A")

How can I store the beta and automate the running of the regression on all stocks?

I would like to have sth like this at the end, with the different stock betas:

| Stock | BX1 | BX2 | BX3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.05 | 0.4 | 0.3 |
| AAPL | 0.02 | 0.5 | 0.3 |
| ACTI | 0.04 | 0.34 | 0.2 |
| AMZ | 0.12 | 0.11 | 0.5 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `tidyverse` approach :

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Stock) %>%
  summarise(model =  list(lm(Return ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = cur_data()))) %>%
  mutate(coeff = map(model, ~.x$coefficients[-1])) %>%
  unnest_wider(coeff) -> result

result
```